# Trouble locating templates in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I can't get my Puppet manifest to find templates the way I'd expect so I thought someone might have a quick answer. I'm new to puppet so just trying to understand all the locations for everything and how to reference files properly. If I'm missing something painfully obvious I apologize.

This works:

```
file {
     $zabbix_agent_conf:
     owner => root,
     group => root,
     mode => 0644,
     content => template("/etc/puppet/templates/zabbix/files/zabbix_agent_conf.erb"),
     require => Package["zabbix-agent"];
}
```

This does not:

```
file {
     $zabbix_agent_conf:
     owner => root,
     group => root,
     mode => 0644,
     content => template("puppet:///templates/zabbix/zabbix_agent_conf.erb"),
     require => Package["zabbix-agent"];
}
```

My /etc/puppet/puppet.conf:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=/etc/puppet/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the puppet URI scheme in combination with the template function as of yet. According to the docs:

> Note that the path to the template doesn’t use the same semantics as
>   the path in a puppet:/// URL. Sorry about the inconsistency. ([Source](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/templates.html#refererring-to-template-files-in-modules))

Furthermore:

> (If a file cannot be located within any module, the template function
>   will fall back to searching relative to the paths in Puppet’s
>   templatedir. However, using this setting is no longer recommended.) ([Source](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html))

This means that in order to use the templatedir the template function expects a simple relative path:

```
template("zabbix/zabbix_agent_conf.erb")
```

It is not recommended to use the templatedir. There is a good reason for this. It is better to group files together under the common denominator of a [module](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/modules_fundamentals.html), otherwise things can get pretty messy pretty fast. Think of modules as a good way to group all puppet resources that belong to each other: manifests, files, templates, extensions and tests.

So I would recommend creating a zabbix module. Place your puppet code in a zabbix class within a init.pp in the manifest directory of your zabbix module. Then you can place your template in the templates directory of your zabbix module and you can reference it by:

```
template("zabbix/zabbix_agent_conf.erb")
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: What you've said here makes a lot of sense and I've actually been thinking along similar lines as far as complexity goes so I think I'll do it the way you suggest. Thanks very much!

Comment: Just an update... Implemented the changes and things are much more manageable. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Puppet URLs are more for sharing between master/agent nodes: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html However they don't work for templates, as mentioned here: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/templates.html#refererring-to-template-files-in-modules

Comment: Thanks xiankai I updated my answer to include your comment for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Once in a module, use

template("${module_name}/xxx.erb")

to reference your template files (works on puppet 4.x. Not sure for previous versions).